# How to initialise new string in loop in C without malloc

Tags: c, scope, malloc, c-strings

I'm trying to instantiate a new string every iteration of a loop. What I tried was this:

```
int main(void) {
  char *strs[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char str[10] = "";
    char c = '0' + i;
    strncat(str, &c, 1);
    strs[i] = str;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
  }
}
```

However, this prints all 9's, since C has conveniently decided that each iteration it would use the same address. I know that the following works, but just wanted to ask if it is possible to avoid malloc.

```
int main(void) {
  char *strs[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    char c = '0' + i;
    strncat(str, &c, 1);
    strs[i] = str;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
  }
}
```

I am also interested in instantiating structs the same way without malloc. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "initializing structs the same way without malloc"? What structs?

Comment: WHK, `strs[i] = str;` is a pointer assignment, not a _string_ assignment.

Comment: Keep in mind that dynamic memory allocation isn't necessary _if_ the data doesn't need to outlive the current scope, isn't too big for the stack, and the size of it can be known at compile time. For your program, `malloc` should not be necessary. If the data is being _copied_ into a data structure at an outer scope, it doesn't need to outlive its scope.

Comment: But if you are going to use `malloc` remember its friend `free`. It's a good habit to develop.

Comment: What I was really aiming for was something like this
`for (...) {
  struct s_type s = (struct s_type) {...};
  printf("%d\n", &s); // all the same struct, I don't want this
}`

Comment: you can't pass a `struct` directly to `printf`, you'll need to write a function like `printStruct(const struct s_type* s){ ... }` and print each field "manually"

Comment: Note that trying to access `strs[i]` in the printing loop is accessing a pointer that's gone out of scope.  That's undefined behaviour on its own.  Mostly, you'll get away with it, but it's a lot easier just to use `malloc()` and `free()`, or maybe (but preferably not) `alloca()`, or avoid needing the dynamic allocation altogether.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach is to declare a two dimensional array like for example

```
  char strs[10][2] = { "" };
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    strs[i][0] = '0' + i;
  }
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char strs[N][2] = { "" };

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        strs[i][0] = '0' + i;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", strs[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Pay attention to that your second program has undefined behavior

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
char c = '0' + i;
strncat(str, &c, 1);
strs[i] = str;
```

The dynamically allocated array is not initialized. So the call of `strncat` invokes undefined behavior.

And in the both your programs this call `strncat(str, &c, 1);` does not build a string. So this call `printf("%s\n", strs[i]);`again invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of data type, an object declared at block scope without storage class specifier `static`<sup>*</sup> has *automatic storage duration*.  Its lifetime ends when execution of the innermost block containing its declaration terminates.  Attempting to access such an object outside its lifetime produces undefined behavior.

If you want an object whose lifetime starts after the beginning of program execution and extends beyond the termination of the innermost block containing the start point, then dynamic allocation is your only choice.

---

<sup>*</sup> *with* `static`, the object has static storage duration -- the whole run of the program.  You can access these via pointer from outside the scope of their identifiers, but for each such declaration there is only object serving the whole execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

> *"just wanted to ask if it is possible to avoid malloc."*

Yes.  The following makes use of [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and a function to do this without using `calloc` or `malloc`.

Running from the command prompt for example, enter:
`your_program_name 10 5<return>` to create an array of 10 elements each having room for 4 `char` plus a terminating null.

```
void populate_strs(int num, int longest, char sArr[num][longest])
{
    for(int i=0;i<num; i++)
    {
        char c[2] = {0};
        c[0] = '0' + (char)i;
        c[1] = 0;//null terminate string
        strncat(sArr[i], c, 1);//do not need & for string
    }
}
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3) printf("Usage error...");

    int num_str = atoi(argv[1]);
    int max_len = atoi(argv[2]);
    char strs[num_str][max_len];
    memset(strs, 0, sizeof strs);
    populate_strs(num_str, max_len, strs);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the same is true for an array of `struct`;

Given this for example:

```
typdef struct {
    int val;
    char str;
    bool state;
} data_s;
...
int size = 0;
printf("Enter how many array elements of data_s to create.\n");
fscanf(stdin, "%d", &size);
data_s data[size];
memset(data, 0, sizeof data);
//use array of data;
```